# Why use Dependency injection when you can import a java class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Could someone please explain to me why do we need to use the spring's dependency injection when you can just import a java class like:

```
import com.package.somejavaclass
```

I just wonder why?

Comment: I think, this an opinion based question, and SO are not accepting that kind of question, anyway, you should read about some [IOC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29271/Design-pattern-Inversion-of-control-and-Dependency) design pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### DI and IoC

[Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (and [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)) have nothing to do with `import`. Dependency injection allows you to make runtime decisions instead of compile-time decisions. For example, how your class gets a database `Connection`. That is configuration over hard-coding.

### `import`

The `import` statement allows you to not specify the fully-qualifed name of a class. That is, without `import java.util.Date;` you can still (for example)

```
System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
```

Comment: You can still have runtime decisions through configuration without DI.

Answer (score 6):

Dependency Injection is used to remove need for the code changes and make it possible using configuration only.

I.e., you have

```
Interface B {
//some methods
}
class X implements B{

// implement some methods of B

}

class Y implements B{

// implement some methods of B

}
// code without using Dependency Injection
 class A1{
private B objB = New X();
//remaining code
}

class A2{
private B objB = New X();
//remaining code
}
```

Note: if you need to change for some reason objB instance with class Y, you need to make code changes in both classes A1 and A2.

```
// code using Dependency Injection
 class A1{

@Autowired
private B objB;
//remaining code
}

class A2{
@Autowired
private B objB;
//remaining code
}
```

Here you just need to change configuration of creating instances for interface B and change required class from X to Y that's it.
No changes in any of java classes (here A1 and A2).

Answer (score 3):

Import - is static import,

Dependency Injection - dynamic import

In addition to @Nirav Patel answer, I would like to add a scenario. If we want to have a different implementation in different environment (Dev/QA/UAT/Prod), you don't need to change the code, you can achieve it using DI and also changing the configuration in that environment.

Watch this video, if you need a detailed explanation

https://www.udemy.com/spring-framework-video-tutorial/learn/v4/t/lecture/4635190

(By the way, it's a free course in Udemy)

Instructor sends a mock email in dev and real email using smtp, just by changing the configuration.